# Bootstrap Colorpicker with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, color-picker

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Colorpicker (http://mjolnic.github.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/) on my website. But later, I found that it doesn't work well with IE8. On IE8, when I try to select color, the colorpicker disappear.

Is there any workaround to make the colorpicker not disappear when selecting color in IE8? Or, is there any other similar colorpicker plugin that works with IE8?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty but [lauren/pick-a-color](http://lauren.github.io/pick-a-color/) states the following support:

`Tested in Chrome (Mac/PC/iOS), Safari (Mac/iOS), IE 8+, Firefox (Mac/PC), and Opera (Mac/PC).`

[image]